# Appending rows to nested rows issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm making a table with nested row's.

The thing is that when I append a child row to a parent row all other parent rows append a child row also.

Use function:

```
$scope.templates=[{src:'template'}];
$scope.include = function(templateURI) {
   $scope.templates.push({src:templateURI});
 }
```

Append row:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm ng-scope" ng-click="include('rowInRow.html')">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
</button>
```

Show template:

```
<div ng-repeat="template in templates">
    <div ng-include="template.src">My template will be visible here</div>
</div>
```

Can somebody give me a hint?
I tried to do it myself but I didn't find what I need.

Comment: would help if it was intuitive what to do in demo and what expected results are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzPF7UFjKyp2tqn27cf4?p=preview

All of the projects are sharing the `templates` collection. Solve this by giving each project its own `templates` array and iterating through that.

Make the `include` function into:

```
$scope.include = function(project, templateURI) {
  if (!project.templates)
    project.templates = [];
    project.templates.push({src:templateURI});
}
```

Call it like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm ng-scope" ng-click="include(project, 'rowInRow.html')">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
</button>
```

Show it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="template in project.templates">
  <div ng-include="template.src">My template will be visible here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cameron!